# How to activate Java Properties Plugin during the Maven JAR project analysis?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1.2

I have a few [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) projects with packaging equal to `JAR` (example: [EasyBundle](https://github.com/gabrysbiz/EasyBundle/)). Unfortunately I cannot see [Java Properties Plugin](https://github.com/racodond/sonar-jproperties-plugin) Quality Profile at project dashboard after analysis:

[image: EasyBundle dashboard]

My project contains `*.properties` files in `src/test/resources` (see [sources](https://github.com/gabrysbiz/EasyBundle/tree/master/src/test/resources/biz/gabrys/easybundle)). How can I activate [Java Properties Plugin](https://github.com/racodond/sonar-jproperties-plugin) during the Maven `JAR` project analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the SonarQube Maven plugin will only index what Maven consider as source folders (ie `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` for a JAR project).

If you want to have files in `src/test/resources` indexed you have to override default configuration either on command line or in your `pom.xml`.

Try: `mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.tests=src/test`

Or add:

```
<properties>
  <sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
</properties>
```

in your `pom.xml`